# How to: Signup And Login Inputs In A Single Form in yii framework

Tags: php, jquery, authentication, yii

**Is it possible to create Login / Sign-Up in one signle form in yii framework**

Has anyone seen any good examples of a Login / Sign-Up in one signle form, uses for both existing users to login and for new members to start a registration process?

Thanks !!!

Comment: It's possible, but you will need to expand the backend logic where the form is handled.

Comment: thanks! can you tell me how to expand the db, or any tutorials or forum links are available?

Comment: I really never worked with YII for that. If thinking outside a framework, it seems a logical conditional task. A single user types user/password/email, you compare it to the db ones, if i.e. the password did not match - raise an error. If all user and email does not exist, instead of raising an error - register the user. I think you just need to change the error handlers to register if both user/email (or what you are using for log/reg) are not present in the db

Comment: OK royal thanks for the response

Comment: I did something like that some time ago, but i had radiobutton to select login or signup. Depence on radio i was rendering diff forms and send it with ajax.

Comment: in my header

    $model=new LoginForm;
    
    $this->renderPartial('//site/login', array('model'=>$model));


on body part

    $model1=new User;
    
    $this->renderPartial('//user/create', array('model'=>$model1));

i have added something like this its works fine..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah,

create your login, and signup textfields.... 
create your rules like if username and password == null => run the register function...
else => run the login function